# When is it ok to store many-many relationships as a single field string instead of columns

Tags: database-design

If I do standard Many to Many table I will potentially have 500k X N! rows. Would it be better to create a delimited string of IDs and parse on retrieval? If so is there a significant performance difference?

Comment: What does "N!" mean to you? What's the expected value of "N"?

Answer (score 5):

Holding more than one value in a column is bad relational design.

Storing such relations in a single field breaks the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (the most basic one).

The implications are:

- Difficult to join on this column
- Difficult to index this column properly
- Difficult to update this column
- Difficult to query on this column
- Difficult to extend and use when requirements change

As an aside - for most relational databases, 500k is not that much, especially for a join table.

So, for many reasons it would be much *worse* to store the relationships in a single delimited field.

In regards to performance - if the join table is properly indexed you will not see much of performance problem. With a single field you need to parse the string for just about *every* operation you do - this is not something relational databases are good at.

Relational databases are optimized for relations through such tables - use them that way.

Comment: what if none of these operations on that column will be happening?

Comment: @zsharp - They might not be happening now, but they might in the future. You want to have a maintainable database schema, right?

Comment: You also lose type-safety, unless your dbms supports array data types. PostgreSQL does, for example, but most platforms used to require you to store multiple values as text.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of a many-to-many table is that it can be indexed so that retrieval of both all children of a parent or all parents of a child can be rapid.

Putting the data in a single string means you can only find (quickly) all children of a parent.

There's a cost to putting stuff in a separate table, but there's also a cost to maintaining/parsing a potentially quite long variable-length string in your record.  DBMS and dev tools have been optimized for years to help with the former, but not with the latter.